# Check if line of movement is blocked

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I have programmed a small top down shooter, but sometimes the AI on both sides get stuck shooting at a wall that separates them. I have tried my hand at writing a function which checks this, but have ended up with a few that will return either true or false even if you input the same things!

The way i try to check it is through this class

```
    class Level{
    public:
        sf::Sprite* background;
        sf::Texture* tex;
        sf::Image* im;
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<sf::Color>> colCollisions;

        int Width, Height;

        Level(std::string name, int width, int height,std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<sf::Color>>col){
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            tex = new sf::Texture();
            im = new sf::Image();
            im->loadFromFile(name);
            tex->loadFromImage(*im);


            background = new sf::Sprite(*tex);
            background->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, width, height));

            colCollisions = col;
        }

        Level(std::string name, int width, int height){
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            tex = new sf::Texture();
            im = new sf::Image();
            im->loadFromFile(name);
            tex->loadFromImage(*im);


            background = new sf::Sprite(*tex);
            background->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, width, height));
        }


        void modulate(sf::RenderWindow& window){
            window.draw(*background);
        }

        bool check(sf::Sprite* s){
            sf::Vector2f pos = s->getPosition();

            if (pos.x<0 || pos.x>Width || pos.y<0 || pos.y>Height){
                return true;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < colCollisions.size(); i++){
                if (colourCollides(pos.x,pos.y, colCollisions[i], im)){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        bool check(int x, int y){

            if (x<0 || x>Width || y<0 || y>Height){
                return true;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < colCollisions.size(); i++){
                if (colourCollides(x,y, colCollisions[i], im)){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

    };
```

Any suggestions or advice would really be appreciated!

Comment: Make your pointers be std::unique_ptr, initialize members in a member initializer list, the second constructor should delegate to the first:  `Level(std::string name, int width, int height) : Level(name, width, height, {}){}`.  Unfortunately, none of this will solve your problem - sorry.

Comment: There's not enough code (I guess `colourCollides()` would be the most likely source of the problem). Besides that, `f (x<0 || x>Width || y<0 || y>Height){` should most likely be `f (x<0 || x>=Width || y<0 || y>=Height){`, if your coordinates are 0-based.

Comment: `if (pos.x<0 || pos.x>Width || pos.y<0 || pos.y>Height)` returns true if outside the bounding box. May be correct, but counter-intuitive.